# Are there any examples of PHP arrays displayed in a editable HTML table form allowing users to delete lines/ values?

Tags: php, html, forms, input, html-table

I'm trying to build a simple HTML table form that displays values from a PHP array. The display part is easy, but I forget how to code form mechanics like selecting and deletion of these values based on user input. I figured they may be an example of something similar online, but have not found anything suitable so far. I am interested in some simple code that allows a user to delete single or multiple lines from a HTML table. I would like to avoid JavaScript or jQuery if possible.

Here is what I have so far:

**HTML/ PHP**

```
<form action="options.php" method="post">
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
        <th>Domain Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
        <th>Domain Name</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    <?php
        foreach ( $my_domains as &$value ) {
            echo '<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>'.$value['domain'].'</td></tr>';
        }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

**PHP ARRAY**

```
Array ( [10] => Array ( [domain] => dsdssd.com ) [11] => Array ( [domain] => google.com ) [12] => Array ( [domain] => new.com ) [13] => Array ( [domain] => blah.com ) )
```

Comment: Maybe you should give an example of the array too? As I understand, you want to delete entries from an array, using only php no JS?

Comment: Good idea. I've added an example array above...

Comment: Well actually, thats the result.. any I have to still manually create the array AND why $value['domain_name'], if in array its just domain. Still, now tell me, what's next now? You want to delete array-entry using those checkboxes? So basically, you could delete multiple domains at once?

Comment: Sorry, got the array value reference wrong. Yes, I would like single-delete and multi-delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So.. In a nutshell. This is what you asked for.. Anyways, you add more options in the form on checkboxex, like which domains are active and so on.. Still, if I was you, I would make this in jQuery and with ajax. Would be much more neater.

Example: http://kopli.pri.ee/stackoverflow/6829783.php

**NOTE** There is no memory. So if basically reload the page in any way, some parts will be reseted.

**EDIT**

This one has the delete all function. It actually uses php fallback aswell as jQuery script to select all. Not sure if its the ultimate way of doing things, so you might want to remove the php fallback option, if your going to use jQuery select all.

Example 2: http://kopli.pri.ee/stackoverflow/6829783_v2.php

*(This is the updated code below)*

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$my_domains[1]['domain'] = 'dsdssd.com';
$my_domains[2]['domain'] = 'google.com';
$my_domains[3]['domain'] = 'new.com';
$my_domains[4]['domain'] = 'blah.com';
$my_domains[5]['domain'] = 'kopli.pri.ee';
$my_domains[6]['domain'] = 'iyfgaming.com';

if ($_POST['trigger']) {
    $p_delete_all = $_POST['delete_all'];
    $p_ids = $_POST['ids']; # Get IDs
    $p_deletes = $_POST['deletes']; # Get deletes
    if ($p_delete_all) {
        unset($my_domains);
    } elseif (is_array($p_ids)) {
        foreach ($p_ids as $id) {
            if ($p_deletes[$id]) {
                unset($my_domains[$id]);
            }
        }
    }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="trigger" value="1">
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="delete_all" value="1"></th>
        <th>Domain Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="delete_all" value="1"></th>
        <th>Domain Name</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    <?php
        if (is_array($my_domains)) {
            foreach ( $my_domains as $array_id => $value ) {
                echo '<input name="ids[]" type="hidden" value="' . $array_id . '">' . "\n";
                echo '<tr><td><input name="deletes[' . $array_id . ']" value="1" type="checkbox"></td><td>'. $value['domain'] . '</td></tr>' . "\n\n";
            }
        } else {
            echo '<tr><td colspan="2">Nothing to display :(</td></tr>';
        }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>

<script>
$('input[name=delete_all]').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('tbody input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
        });
        $('input[name=delete_all]').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('tbody input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
        });
        $('input[name=delete_all]').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I updated the code to have the delete all function, with php fallback, if javascript isn't enabled.

Comment: I assume that it worked :) If so, then don't forget to click on the green birdie next to the answer ;)